# Setting up Pre auth filter for CasAuthenticationFilter

Tags: spring-security, cas, jasig, spring-security-cas

I've a Spring Jasig CAS SSO set up for a couple of applications. This uses `CasAuthenticationFilter`. So I've webapps set up like these -

`Cas Server (Cas 3.5.2) - Cas.war`, `App1 - App1.war` and `App2 - App2.war`. Applications use Spring 3.2.3 and Spring Security 3.1.4.RELEASE.

`Spring Security Config`: http://pastie.org/private/qxcx1h8i9ys0w3lmwegiw

Things seem to work normally with this setup. Now, when I enable OAuth at the Cas Server (not through Spring Cas), I'm unable to integrate that authentication with the usual form-based authentication that I've set up. Facebook OAuth integration seems to work fine as I can see facebook profile attributes successfully retrieved in the logs. The problem is that post facebook login, CasAuthenticationFilter tries to authenticate the user "FacebookProfile#XYZXYZ" with a similar mechanism for form-based login and obviously it doesn't find that user in the database table for users. My guess is that I need to write a custom filter that extends `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` and with position before `PRE_AUTH_FILTER` (check the pastie configuration above) and that should somehow set the `Authentication` right, so `CasAuthenticationFilter` should know that the user is already logged in.

This is the URL being authenticated by `CasAuthenticationFilter` as per the logs - `/j_spring_cas_security_proxyreceptor?pgtIou=PGTIOU-1-pR9r9LVJvB5EkezbMJHN-talenteye.in&pgtId=TGT-2-QXvAHIRciBNR9HU5FOvpOaHcJaBj5OJTUPPz5ZwA7yK1xH54iL-myorg.in`

The implementation `requiresAuthentication` of `CasAuthenticationFilter` looks like this:

```
protected boolean requiresAuthentication(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) {
    final boolean serviceTicketRequest = serviceTicketRequest(request, response);
    final boolean result = serviceTicketRequest || proxyReceptorRequest(request) || (proxyTicketRequest(serviceTicketRequest, request));
    if(logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("requiresAuthentication = "+result);
    }
    return result;
}
```

And the logs say -

```
19:23:42.835 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.c.web.CasAuthenticationFilter -     serviceTicketRequest = false
19:23:42.835 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.c.web.CasAuthenticationFilter - proxyReceptorConfigured = true
19:23:42.835 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.c.web.CasAuthenticationFilter - proxyReceptorRequest = true
19:23:42.835 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.c.web.CasAuthenticationFilter - requiresAuthentication = true
19:23:42.835 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.c.web.CasAuthenticationFilter - Request is to process authentication
19:23:42.835 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.c.web.CasAuthenticationFilter - proxyReceptorConfigured = true
19:23:42.835 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.c.web.CasAuthenticationFilter - proxyReceptorRequest = true
19:23:42.835 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.c.web.CasAuthenticationFilter - Responding to proxy receptor request
```

I'm confused as to how to make this work together. I wonder if I'm complicating things a bit too much. Any pointers will be really helpful as I've already wasted a couple of days on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this myself and hence posting here for others who face similar issues.

The whole point of using CAS is to centralize the authentication. I wrote a custom class that extends `AbstractCasAssertionUserDetailsService`. This doesn't do the authentication. It has to be done on the CAS server. This just prepares a `UserDetails` object which is used by the CAS client web applications. So, PRE-AUTH was not needed in my case. Also, I got rid of unneeded proxy receptor configuration. It works well now.